# QuantLib 1.5 compiling error cannot open file 'QuantLib-vc100-x64-mt.lib'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compilation, quantlib

I have already installed boost library `v1.57.0 (x64)` via the binary file, which works properly under my `VS2010Pro`.

However, when I tried to compile the latest version (v1.5) of QuantLib, by opening `QuantLib_vc10.sln` file, for both 'Debug' and 'Release' under 'x64' in VS2010, I got something like:

> QuantLib.vcxproj -> ...\QuantLib-1.5.\lib\QuantLib--x64-mt.lib

in the 1st project, then 18 failed build with the error:

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'QuantLib-vc100-x64-mt.lib'

It is clear that the fatal error is due to the incapability of naming library with 'vc100' in the 1st project. But I don't know how to fix the problem.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The version tag should be taken care of in the `QuantLib.props` file, which in imported in the project.  From searching a bit, though, it looks like the `VisualStudioVersion` property (which we're relying on) might not be defined in VS10.  Try editing `QuantLib.props`, and adding

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

before the other two `PropertyGroup`s, and relinking the library (and please, let me know if this works so I can patch the file in the next release).

Comment: Hello Luigi, yes it works now. Thanks! Just out of curiosity, how to change the part you suggested to add in order to be used for VS2013 Express version?